# How to write file to Hololens from UWP app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, file-writing

I am developing a UWP app for the HoloLens 2 with Unity. I want to write to a log file (to record user interactions), and then later retrieve that file. I do not want the user to have to select a file location.

The following code works on Desktop UWP app (output from same code and same Unity project). It does NOT work on the HoloLens, but instead throws an "Unauthorized" Exception. How can I write to a file on the HoloLens? And where can I find that file later?

```
public class Logger : MonoBehaviour
{
    StreamWriter logFileWriter;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        string fileName = "mydatalog.csv";

        // Creates a file in the default location:
        //      "build\bin\x64\Release\AppX" on Desktop
        this.logFileWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        string record = // Stuff here...

        if (this.logFileWriter != null)
        {
            this.logFileWriter.WriteLine(record);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that your application meets with the [UWP File system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) policy and has the permission to access the device resources. Besides, "build\bin\x64\Release\AppX" this directory path seems like an output project that builds from Unity, and the application install directory deploying on the HoloLens from Visual Studio is different from it.

Comment: We recommend that you use the file directory path provided by Unity API Application.persistentDataPath to store data, or using the UWP API Windows.Storage to manage files.

Comment: Is there a way for me to later manually retrieve files saved there? For example, going through file explorer? This project is for academic research, and I just need the app to log data while running during the experiment/study session. I will then manually take that log data and work with it later.

Comment: Karina Rigby's answer will meet your need, it also is one of the recommended way to save files for us. Please feel free to let us know your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try setting the filepath to write to `Application.persistentDataPath`? In [Unity's docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) it says for Windows applications that the path points to

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\<productname>\LocalState
```

so that's the path where you would look for the files on your desktop later.

I used to write persistent data there when I was working with Hololens. Afterwards, through the Hololens portal on desktop I could navigate to that file that I wrote.

I haven't worked with Hololens 2 but I don't think that the process would be very different.

Comment: This works beautifully for desktop. Problem I am having now is that the "ApplicationData" folder on the Hololens appears empty when trying to view it on desktop, and I cannot seem to view it on the Hololens itself.

Comment: @MichaelKintscher Are you using the Hololens Developer Portal to try and access this? To see the data in that particular path you need to access it through the Hololens Developer portal. Check out this link for [file viewing on the Hololens through the Dev portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/using-the-windows-device-portal#file-explorer) by Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the Documents folder within the HoloLens device is possible through code without using a File selector. Here is a helper file I created for reading files, I haven’t tested with writing but it should be similar.

> Within visual studio you may see the section within #if WINDOWS_UWP gray out, to fix this change from Assembly-CSharp to Assembly-CSharp.Player
> [(How to Change It)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVBFY.png)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class FileHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static string path;

    private void Start()
    {
        path = Application.streamingAssetsPath;

#if WINDOWS_UWP
        Task pathTask = new Task(
            async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var folders = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFoldersAsync();

                    if (folders != null && folders.Count > 0) FileHelper.path = folders[0].Path.Substring(0, folders[0].Path.LastIndexOfAny(new char[2] { '/', '\\' }));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Failed to locate documents folder!");
                }
            });

        pathTask.Start();
#endif
    }

    public static string ReadFile(string filename)
    {
        string content = string.Empty;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, filename)))
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(path, filename));
                if (reader == null) return string.Empty;
                content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

        return content;
    }
}
```

This won't work on its own through you must edit the package manifest file when building to include the correct permissions for accessing the documents folder. To accomplish this within the MRTK build window, you first click on ‘Build Unity Project’.

Once you have built the project before we can build the APPX package, we must edit the manifest file, this can be located at:

*Your Project/Temp/StagingArea/Package.appxmanifest*

Open the file with a code editor like Visual Studio Code, we must add the capability of docuentsLibrary and include which file types we’ll be using as an extension. To add the extension you must place it under the VisualElements closing tag within the Application selection. You can add as many file types as you need, currently I included ‘.json’ and ‘.data’ files.

Here is the section of the mainifest file I'll edit before adding the capability and filetpye specifier: (Line 16 to Line 35)

```
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="ARIVE.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="HoloLens File Reader" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Template_3D" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" />
        <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portraitFlipped" />
        </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <uap2:Capability Name="spatialPerception" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="gazeinput" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Here is the updated version: (Line 16 to Line 47)

```
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="ARIVE.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="HoloLens File Reader" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Template_3D" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" />
        <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portraitFlipped" />
        </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      </uap:VisualElements>

      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="waypoint">
            <uap:DisplayName>waypoint list</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.json</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.data</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>

    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>

    <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />

    <uap2:Capability Name="spatialPerception" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="gazeinput" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Now that you have the manifest updated you can go back into Unity and click on the 'Build APPX' button within the MRTK build window.